# How would I go about creating roles with google+ hangouts api?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I want to develop a quick prototype as a google hangouts app.

The basic gist of the app -> it's a public speaking app that will allow you to practice speeches in front of friends.

The first hurdle I need to get over is assigning a "speaker" role:

Say there are 9 people in the room (which I also need to make the max number of participants allowed), and one of them will be the speaker/presenter, while the other 8 are the audience members. The speaker's video feed will need to be the only thing that the other viewers can see (no switching to other video feeds).

There are other features such as a timer that starts once the speaker clicks a "start speech" button, and viewers will have a "ready" button to let the speaker know they are ready to listen. There also needs to be a button at the start of the app to decide who is the speaker.

All of these features and more are dependent on assigning the role of speaker and audience first.

I'm looking at some game code from some hangout game apps, since it seems a lot of games would need to assign roles, but a lot of it looks confusing to me. I know html/xml, css, and a little bit of javascript. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an app with the timer and so on and use a Video Canvas to display the feed of your choice - you could have the speaker be the person that starts the app, or have a button for people to self-select.

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/controlling-video-feeds

With regards to participant limits - the limit is 10 people by default, so you shouldn't need to do any work there.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if I can use the on-air functions in `gapi.hangout.onair` without having a live broadcast? I can use `setDisplayedParticipantInBroadcast(id)` for the "speaker" if so.